# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header contains multiple values '*, *' on staging server, but not on dev server; Where is header being added?

Tags: cors

I have a shopify page that makes an ajax call to one of my site's controllers in order to load the content of the site's header. I have a script on my shopify page that references a javascript file, and the javascript file makes an Ajax call to the controller. In my js file, when I point the Ajax call to the controller on the dev server (e.g. http://dweb.mysite.org/HeaderContent/GetContent) it works and I get the info I'm requesting. However, when I change the Ajax call to point to the staging server (http://sweb.mysite.org/HeaderContent/GetContent), I get an error that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header contains multiple values '*, *'

I can see in fiddler the header is added twice.

From dweb:

[image: 1]

From sweb:

[image: 2]

How can I figure out where the header is being added? It must be a setting on the staging server that's different from the dev server, but I just don't know where to look. If it helps, the site is an Amazon s3 site

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar issue within IIS. I'm not sure what Web Server you were using but I imagine there are similar settings.

I discovered that IIS was adding in an additional HTTP Response Header. I simply removed this additional header from within IIS->HTTP Response Headers and my issue was resolved.

Check your Web Server and see if it is adding in an additional Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with a value of *.